# Drawing elliptical orbit in Python (using numpy, matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, orbit

I wonder how can I draw elliptical orbit by using the equation ay<sup>2</sup> + bxy + cx + dy + e = x<sup>2</sup> ?

I have first determined the a,b,c,d,e constants and now I assume by giving x values I will obtain y and this will give me the graph I want but I couldn't do it by using matplotlib.

I would really appreciate, if you could help me!

EDIT: I added the code here.

```
from numpy import linalg
from numpy import linspace
import numpy as np
from numpy import meshgrid
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

x = [1.02, 0.95, 0.87, 0.77, 0.67, 0.56, 0.44, 0.30, 0.16, 0.01]
y = [0.39, 0.32, 0.27, 0.22, 0.18, 0.15, 0.13, 0.12, 0.12, 0.15]

my_list = [] #It is the main list.
b = [0] * len(x) # That is the list that contains the results that are given as x^2 from the equation.

def fxn():  # That is the function that solves the given equation to find each parameter.
    global my_list
    global b
    for z in range(len(x)):
        w = [0] * 5
        w[0] = y[z] ** 2
        w[1] = x[z] * y[z]
        w[2] = x[z]
        w[3] = y[z]
        w[4] = 1
        my_list.append(w)
        b[z] = x[z] ** 2

    t = linalg.lstsq(my_list, b)[0]
    print 'List of list representation is', my_list
    print 'x^2, the result of the given equation is', b
    print '\nThe list that contains the parameters is', t

fxn()
t = linalg.lstsq(my_list, b)[0]

print '\nThe constant a is', t[0]
print 'The constant b is', t[1]
print 'The constant c is', t[2]
print 'The constant d is', t[3]
print 'The constant e is', t[4]
```

EDIT: Here are the constant values:

```
a = -4.10267300566
b = 1.10642410023
c = 0.39735696603
d = 3.05101004127
e = -0.370426134994
```

Comment: Relevant to your question (very similar question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29582089/how-to-plot-an-ellipse-by-its-equation-on-python

Comment: Can you print the output for the value of each constant?

Comment: I added them in the OP.

Comment: I am working on an answer for you. Almost done.

Comment: cheers! I have been trying to plot it for hours and couldn't manage, hope it works man!

Comment: @aleatha "I assume by giving x values I will obtain y" But where in the code are you doing this?

Comment: I have to find roots for x and y  but since there are two roots for each given value (due to ellipse's shape), I keep failing on that. The equation d=B^2-4AC should be the case here.

Comment: I tried it in different function not in the code that I have given above. I have to use these new x and y values in matplot to draw ellipse.

Comment: Posted. Finding roots per-se won't help. You have to find where dx/dy goes to zero (vertical tangent points), and parametrize everything between those points. It's much easier to do what I did and rotate stuff around until you get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved for y as a function of x

The catch is that there are 2 values of y for every valid x, and no (or imaginary) y solutions outside the range of x the ellipse spans

below is 3.5 code, sympy 1.0 should be fine but print, list comps may not be backwards compatable to 2.x

```
from numpy import linalg
from numpy import linspace
import numpy as np
from numpy import meshgrid
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
from sympy import *

xs = [1.02, 0.95, 0.87, 0.77, 0.67, 0.56, 0.44, 0.30, 0.16, 0.01]
ys = [0.39, 0.32, 0.27, 0.22, 0.18, 0.15, 0.13, 0.12, 0.12, 0.15]

b = [i ** 2 for i in xs] # That is the list that contains the results that are given as x^2 from the equation.

def fxn(x, y):  # That is the function that solves the given equation to find each parameter.
    my_list = [] #It is the main list.
    for z in range(len(x)):
        w = [0] * 5
        w[0] = y[z] ** 2
        w[1] = x[z] * y[z]
        w[2] = x[z]
        w[3] = y[z]
        w[4] = 1
        my_list.append(w)
    return my_list

t = linalg.lstsq(fxn(xs, ys), b)


def ysolv(coeffs):
    x,y,a,b,c,d,e = symbols('x y a b c d e')
    ellipse = a*y**2 + b*x*y + c*x + d*y + e - x**2
    y_sols = solve(ellipse, y)
    print(*y_sols, sep='\n')

    num_coefs = [(a, f) for a, f in (zip([a,b,c,d,e], coeffs))]
    y_solsf0 = y_sols[0].subs(num_coefs)
    y_solsf1 = y_sols[1].subs(num_coefs)

    f0 = lambdify([x], y_solsf0)
    f1 = lambdify([x], y_solsf1)
    return f0, f1

f0, f1 = ysolv(t[0])

y0 = [f0(x) for x in xs]
y1 = [f1(x) for x in xs]

plt.scatter(xs, ys)
plt.scatter(xs, y0, s=100, color = 'red', marker='+')
plt.scatter(xs, y1, s=100, color = 'green', marker='+')
plt.show()
```

when the above is ran in Spyder:

```
runfile('C:/Users/john/mypy/mySE_answers/ellipse.py', wdir='C:/Users/john/mypy/mySE_answers')
(-b*x - d + sqrt(-4*a*c*x - 4*a*e + 4*a*x**2 + b**2*x**2 + 2*b*d*x + d**2))/(2*a)
-(b*x + d + sqrt(-4*a*c*x - 4*a*e + 4*a*x**2 + b**2*x**2 + 2*b*d*x + d**2))/(2*a)
```

[image]
   ￼
The generated functions for the y values aren't  valid everywhere:

```
f0(0.1), f1(0.1)
Out[5]: (0.12952825130864626, 0.6411040771593166)

f0(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-9ce260237dcd>", line 1, in <module>
    f0(2)

  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>

ValueError: math domain error


In [7]:
```

The domain error would require a try/execpt to "feel out" the valid x range or some more math

like the try/except below: (Edited to "close" drawing re comment )

```
def feeloutXrange(f, midx, endx):
    fxs = []
    x = midx
    while True:
        try: f(x)
        except:
            break
        fxs.append(x)
        x += (endx - midx)/100
    return fxs

midx = (min(xs) + max(xs))/2    

xpos = feeloutXrange(f0, midx, max(xs))
xnegs = feeloutXrange(f0, midx, min(xs))
xs_ellipse = xnegs[::-1] + xpos[1:]

y0s = [f0(x) for x in xs_ellipse]
y1s = [f1(x) for x in xs_ellipse]

ys_ellipse = y0s + y1s[::-1] + [y0s[0]] # add y start point to end to close drawing

xs_ellipse = xs_ellipse + xs_ellipse[::-1] + [xs_ellipse[0]] # added x start point


plt.scatter(xs, ys)
plt.scatter(xs, y0, s=100, color = 'red', marker='+')
plt.scatter(xs, y1, s=100, color = 'green', marker='+')
plt.plot(xs_ellipse, ys_ellipse)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit: added duplicate start point to the end of ellipse point lists to close the plot figure

```
ys_ellipse = y0s + y1s[::-1] + [y0s[0]] # add y start point to end to close drawing

xs_ellipse = xs_ellipse + xs_ellipse[::-1] + [xs_ellipse[0]] # added x start point
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is also working for my in python 2.7 but I didn't understand why is there a gap at around x = 1 ? I am trying to fix it at the moment

Comment: I had fun using sympy to solve symbolically for y, then subs the numerical coefficients and dynamically creating the functions for the 2 solutions of the y quadratic.   Also couldn't resist showing a more functional programming style.  Closing the drawing just requires understanding that a line plot "connects the dots" in your x,y points lists.

Answer (score 3):

## Intro

Easiest thing would be to parametrize this equation. As @Escualo suggests, you could introduce a variable `t` and parametrize `x` and `y` along that. Parametrizing means separating your equation into two separate equations for `x` and `y` individually in terms of `t`. So you would have `x = f(t)` and `y = g(t)` for some values of `t`. You could then plot the `x, y` pairs that result for each value of `t`.

The catch here is that your ellipse is rotated (the `x*y` coupling term is an indication of that). To separate the equations, you have to first transform the equation to get rid of the coupling term. This is the same as finding a set of axes that are rotated by the same angle as the ellipse, parametrzing along those axes, then rotating the result back. Check out [this forum post](http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=17029) for a general overview.

## Math

You first need to find the angle of rotation of the ellipse's axes with respect to the x-y coordinate plane.

[image: \theta = \frac{1}{2} tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{-1 - a})]

Your equation then transforms to

[image: a'x'^2+b'y'^2+c'x+d'y'+e=0]

where

[image: a'=-cos^2(\theta)+b*sin(\theta)cos(\theta)+a*sin^2(\theta)]

[image: b'=-sin^2(\theta)-b*sin(\theta)cos(\theta)+a*cos^2(\theta)]

[image: c'=c*cos(\theta)+d*sin(\theta)]

[image: d'=-c*sin(\theta)+d*cos(\theta)]

[image: e'=e]

To find the (nearly) standard form of the ellipse, you can complete the squares for the [image: x'] and [image: y'] portions and rearrange the equation slightly:

[image: \frac{(x'-h)^2}{a''^2}+\frac{(y'-k)^2}{b''^2}=c'']

where

[image: a''=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a'}}]

[image: b''=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b'}}]

[image: c''=\frac{c'^2}{4a'}+\frac{d'^2}{4b'}-e']

[image: h=-\frac{c'}{2a'}]

[image: k=-\frac{d'}{2b'}]

Since you know [image: \theta], you can now parametrize the equations for [image: x'] and [image: y']:

[image: x'=h+a''\sqrt{c''}sin(t)]

[image: y'=k+b''\sqrt{c''}cos(t)]

You would then rotate back into normal x-y space using the formulas

[image: x=x'cos(\theta)-y'sin(\theta)]

and

[image: y=x'sin(\theta)+y'cos(\theta)]

## Code

The code to get the x- and y- arrays to pass to `plt.plot` is now relatively straightforward:

```
def computeEllipse(a, b, c, d, e):
    """
    Returns x-y arrays for ellipse coordinates.
    Equation is of the form a*y**2 + b*x*y + c*x + d*y + e = x**2
    """
    # Convert x**2 coordinate to +1
    a = -a
    b = -b
    c = -c
    d = -d
    e = -e
    # Rotation angle
    theta = 0.5 * math.atan(b / (1 - a))
    # Rotated equation
    sin = math.sin(theta)
    cos = math.cos(theta)
    aa = cos**2 + b * sin * cos + a * sin**2
    bb = sin**2 - b * cos * sin + a * cos**2
    cc = c * cos + d * sin
    dd = -c * sin + d * cos
    ee = e
    # Standard Form
    axMaj = 1 / math.sqrt(aa)
    axMin = 1 / math.sqrt(bb)
    scale = math.sqrt(cc**2 / (4 * aa) + dd**2 / (4 * bb) - ee)
    h = -cc / (2 * aa)
    k = -dd / (2 * bb)
    # Parametrized Equation
    t = np.linspace(0, 2 * math.pi, 1000)
    xx = h + axMaj * scale * np.sin(t)
    yy = k + axMin * scale * np.cos(t)
    # Un-rotated coordinates
    x = xx * cos - yy * sin
    y = xx * sin + yy * cos

    return x, y
```

To actually use the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

a = -4.10267300566
b = 1.10642410023
c = 0.39735696603
d = 3.05101004127
e = -0.370426134994

lines = plt.plot(*computeEllipse(a, b, c, d, e))
```

To overplot your original points on the ellipse:

```
x = [1.02, 0.95, 0.87, 0.77, 0.67, 0.56, 0.44, 0.30, 0.16, 0.01]
y = [0.39, 0.32, 0.27, 0.22, 0.18, 0.15, 0.13, 0.12, 0.12, 0.15]
ax = lines[0].axes
ax.plot(x, y, 'r.')
```

The result is the following image:

[image: plot]

## Note

Keep in mind that the forum post I linked to uses a different notation than the one you do. Their equation is *Ax<sup>2</sup> + Bxy + Cy<sup>2</sup> + Dx + Ey + F = 0*. This is a bit more standard than your form of *ay<sup>2</sup> + bxy - x<sup>2</sup> + cx + dy + e = 0*. All of the math is in terms of your notation.

Comment: Yes, it is different, but thank you very much for your helps!! I will be reading more about this today. The answer prior to yours also worked for me and now I am trying to understand what is done there in more detail, thank you very much again.

Comment: @aleatha. I updated my answer with a fix to the scaling factor. The sqrt(c'') factor is actually multiplicative, not divisive for the length of the axes. It also does not apply to h and k. This solution has the advantage of being very fast to compute (just simple math, no fancy optimizations), and that it can be applied to any ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is rewrite in parametric form so that you end up with the expressions `x = A cos(t)`; `y = B sin(t)`. You then create a full ellipse by assigning `t = [0, 2 * pi]` and calculating the corresponding `x` and `y`.

Read [this article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html) which explains how to move from a general quadratic form into a parametric form.

Comment: This won't work because the ellipse is rotated. You can't solve for x and y directly in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, I really do not have an understanding of those cos, sin in this case. I thought there would be a easy way of doing it since it is library dependent code. I just need to assign new y values by giving x certain values in a specific range.