# Draw ellipse on an image given its foci

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I wish to draw an ellipse on an image. I have both of its foci and a constant d [(being the length red line here and in the example)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/ellipse.gif). Most of the standard drawing packages like Pillow require a bounding box for an eclipse, and I have no clue how I would calculate it from the foci. I've found a way in [matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264232/draw-ellipse-in-matplotlib-given-the-focii), but since I'm trying to draw the ellipse, I can't use matplotlib.

So how do I draw an ellipse given its foci?

[image: example ellipse]

Comment: The foci alone do not uniquely determine an ellipse.  You'd need one additional parameter before you even have a solvable problem here - the eccentricity, perhaps.

Comment: @jasonharper oops, I forgot to mention the d, fixed. Good catch, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Is the ellipse always axis-aligned?  Your `d` parameter seems quite convenient for calculating the bounding box - horizontal bounds are outset from the foci by `(d - (x2-x1))/2`.  Vertical bounds require a little help from Pythagoras - `sqrt((d/2)**2 - (x2-x1)**2)` above and below the Y coordinate of the foci.  (If it's *not* axis-aligned, you're not going to be able to use Pillow's ellipse drawing function anyway.)

Comment: It's not, but I bet I could calculate it that way and then apply a rotation.

Comment: You could make the PIL Image into a Numpy array and use the scikit-image method https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html?highlight=ellipse#skimage.draw.ellipse or the OpenCV method https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga28b2267d35786f5f890ca167236cbc69