# MATLAB curve fitting for ellipse

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, curve-fitting, least-squares

How can I fit `ay2 + bxy + cx + dy + e = x2` in MATLAB ? I have the values of the coefficients which I got using '\'. I need to plot the points and fit a curve for a regression problem. I think it should form an ellipse but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Define _fit the curve_. Do you have a cloud of points and want to minimize some discrepancy metric?

Comment: I have made the requested edits

Comment: Check (this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116977/how-can-i-fit-an-equation-which-is-not-a-function) and the links therein.